# SUMIF parse error

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to choose from dropdown list in `L1` (same as J2:J600) and sum up all prices from `F` with specified value from `J`.

[image]

Comment: What is the `#ERROR` you are getting? Can you share an example spreadsheet with us?

Comment: Here You go: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QagDyMkMcsEYUQA70JB0wj-mNvOCi5MZXoNhxohUMMk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `,` with `;`:

```
   =SUMIF(J2:J600; L1;F2:F600)
```

Your country uses `,` as decimal separator and thus cannot be used in any formula.

Comment: That's it! Tnx!